# What is the difference between Private and Local scope -In Powershell?

Tags: .net, powershell, scope, powershell-2.0

Can you please explain the difference between Private and Local scope?

If we speak on an example, if I I create a new PS Drive with scope Private what is the difference compared to creating it with Local scope?

Thanks

Comment: what about `get-help about_scopes` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Local vars are visible in child scopes (nested script blocks, functions called etc.) Private vars are only visible in the current script block. A simple example:

```
PS> & { $local:foo = 42; $private:bar = 42; & { "foo is $foo and bar is $bar" } }
foo is 42 and bar is
```

As you can see, `$bar` is not visible to the inner script block.